# Question about sum of chi-squared distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I want to prove that the sum of two independent chi-squared random variables is a chi-squared random variable.

I am supposed to only use the fact that if $Q$ has a chi-squared distribution with parameter k then Q = $Z_1^2$ + $Z_2^2$ + ... + $Z_k^2$ where each $Z_i$ is a standard normally distributed random variable and {$Z_1$,...,$Z_k$} is independent.

My attempt at a proof:

Let $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be independent random variables with chi-squared distributions, with parameters a and b, respectively.
Let {$X_1$,...,$X_a$,$Y_1$,...,$Y_b$} be a set of independent random variables with standard normal distributions. Then we can write

$Q_1$ = $X_1^2$ + $X_2^2$ + ... + $X_a^2$

$Q_2$ = $Y_1^2$ + $Y_2^2$ + ... + $Y_b^2$  , and $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are independent because {$X_1$,...,$X_a$,$Y_1$,...,$Y_b$} is independent.

so $Q_2$ + $Q_2$ = $X_1^2$ + $X_2^2$ + ... + $X_a^2$ + $Y_1^2$ + $Y_2^2$ + ... + $Y_b^2$.

Since {$X_1$,...,$X_a$,$Y_1$,...,$Y_b$} is independent, $Q_2$ + $Q_2$ is a chi-squared random variable with parameter a+b.

I don't think my proof is correct. I think the problem is that if we are given $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ that are independent, we can't just write them in terms of {$X_1$,...,$X_a$,$Y_1$,...,$Y_b$}. But I am not really sure. Please tell me why my proof is incorrect (or maybe it is correct). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In my view your proof is correct (and nice too). If you are still suspicious then you could use the [characteristic functions](http://www.planetmathematics.com/CentralChiDistr.pdf) of the distributions.

Comment: "We can't just write them in terms of..." Yes, we can! And in many cases we should, since this practice is very fruitful. Just as a binomial can be written as finite sum of Bernouillis. Very handsome e.g. if expectations must be calculated.

Comment: I guess what I am a bit confused about is: we know that Q1 can be written as a sum of the squares of independent standard normal variables {A1,A2,...,Am} and Q2 can be written as a sum of the squares of independent standard normal variables {B1,B2,...,Bn} (I am not confused about this), but how can we be sure that {A1,...,Am,B1,...,Bn} is independent?

Comment: See my answer with an accent on *start*. We are sure of the independence of the $A_i$ and $B_j$ because we *preassume* them to be independent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just **start** with independent standard normal variables $\{A_1,\dots,A_m,B_1,\dots,B_n\}$ and define: $$Q_1=A_1^2+\cdots+A_m^2$$ $$Q_2=B_1^2+\cdots+B_n^2$$ $$Q=A_1^2+\cdots+A_m^2+B_1^2+\cdots+B_n^2$$
Then $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are independent and both have chi-squared distribution with parameters $m$ and $n$ respectively.

Also it is clear that $Q_1+Q_2=Q$ and that $Q$ has chi-squared distribution with parameter $m+n$.

Proved is now that a sum of two independent rv's with chi-squared distribution also has chi-squared distribution. Its parameter is the sum of the parameters of its terms.

---

What follows can be left out and must be seen as an effort to make your understanding complete:

If $Q_1'$ and $Q_2'$ are independent chi-squared distributions with parameters $m$ and $n$ respectively that 'show up somewhere' then:

- $Q_1'$ and $Q_1$ have the same distribution.
- $Q_2'$ and $Q_2$ have the same distribution.
- $Q':=Q_1'+Q_2'$ and $Q=Q_1+Q_2$ have the same distribution.

Comment: I think this is correct. Thank you very much for explaining it to me so clearly!

Comment: You are very welcome.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the very last step of your answer?

Comment: @ThighCrush The distribution of $Q$ is completely determined by the joint distribution of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$. But this distribution is the same as the joint distribution of $Q_1^'$ and $Q_2^'$. This distribution determines similarly the distribution of $Q'$. If things are still not clear then find characteristic functions of $Q$ and $Q'$. They both turn out to be the product of the characteristic functions of $Q_1$ and $Q_2$.

Comment: @drhab Bit late, but thank you for your answer! I remember understanding your answer at the time but I never got around to thanking you.

Comment: @ThighCrush You are (still :-)) very welcome.