# Sum of Squared Independent Normal Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, chi-squared

Although this question has been extensively studied since 100 years ago, I am getting tired of not finding an answer for this in the literature:

> If $X_i$s are independent normal random variables with mean $\mu_i$ and variance $\sigma_i^2$, then what is the probability density function (PDF) of $z=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2$?

Can you please give me a closed form of the PDF and the CDF?

Comment: I think [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096298/question-about-sum-of-chi-squared-distribution) you have a solution to your question.

Comment: @Masacroso Thanks. But they are talking about standard normal random variables. In my question, I don't have normal random variables.

Comment: If $\sigma_i$ are identical, then you have (scaled) non-central chi square.